# MongoDB slow read speeds? Speeding up reading of cursor data and iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have data that is pickled as a `numpy` matrix and stored in `MongoDB`. My matrix is generated as follows and has dimensions `32000x464`.

```
import numpy as np
dtype = "float32"
matrix = np.random.rand(32000,464).astype(dtype)
```

I insert 464 individual `32000x1` pickled `numpy` arrays  as follows into `MongoDB`:

```
list_to_insert = list()
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
channel_resolution=1
while index<(464-channel_resolution): 
    list_to_insert.append({"index" : current_time, "RawData" : pickle.dumps(matrix[:,index:(index+channel_resolution)]), "StartChannel" : index+1, "EndChannel" : index+channel_resolution, "Processed" : False})
    index = index + channel_resolution
raw_data_collection.insert_many(list_to_insert)
```

I then would like to query a particular channel over a particular timeframe, using something like the following:

```
mongo_client = mongo_connect()
time_duration_minutes = 1
raw_data_collection  = mongo_client["RawData"]
maxChannel = random.randint(num_channel_to_read+1,464)
minChannel = maxChannel - num_channel_to_read + 1
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
raw_data_query = {"index" : {"$lt" : current_time,"$gt" : current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=time_duration_minutes)}, "$or": [{"StartChannel" : {"$gte" : minChannel, "$lte" : maxChannel}}, {"EndChannel" : {"$gte" : minChannel, "$lte" : maxChannel}}] }

raw_data_result = raw_data_collection.find(raw_data_query, {"RawData" : 1, "_id" : 0}).sort("index", -1).allow_disk_use(True)
raw_data_result.batch_size(10000)
theArray = list(raw_data_result)
```

The above queries the past one minute of a particular channel. I would like to access the "RawData" indexes for the data entries that match the query. As can be seen, I try to convert the `cursor` to a `list` using

```
theArray = list(raw_data_result)
```

However, it appears to never finish, at least within the 5 or 10 minutes that I have waited. Perhaps it would finish at some point, but regardless, the point is that it is too slow for this application. I was hoping for a few seconds.

I have also tried iterating over a loop with the following:

```
for i in range(num_ierations):
    raw_data_start_read_time = time.perf_counter()
    for raw_data in raw_data_result: 
        RawData = pickle.loads(raw_data["RawData"])
        if full_raw_data is None : 
            full_raw_data = RawData
        else: 
            full_raw_data = np.concatenate((full_raw_data,RawData),axis=0)
    RAW_data_read_times.append(time.perf_counter() - raw_data_start_read_time)
```

However, similarly, the program seems to become stuck and never moves past the first execution of `for raw_data in raw_data_result`, which is the first indexing into the `raw_data_result` cursor.

Effectively, my data is inaccessible currently in MongoDB. Is there something that I am doing wrong? How can I speed this up to take only a few seconds?

**Edit** I thought something funky might be going on with my query, so I changed the following:

```
raw_data_result = raw_data_collection.find(raw_data_query, {"RawData" : 1, "_id" : 0}).sort("index", -1).allow_disk_use(True)
```

To the following:

```
raw_data_result = raw_data_collection.find(raw_data_query)
```

This did not seem to result in any difference.

**Edit** For what it's worth, when I set a breakpoint and run `raw_data_result.count()`, I receive the following message:

```
Evaluating: raw_data_result.count() did not finish after 3.00 seconds.
This may mean a number of things:
- This evaluation is really slow and this is expected.
    In this case it's possible to silence this error by raising the timeout, setting the
    PYDEVD_WARN_EVALUATION_TIMEOUT environment variable to a bigger value.

- The evaluation may need other threads running while it's running:
    In this case, it's possible to set the PYDEVD_UNBLOCK_THREADS_TIMEOUT
    environment variable so that if after a given timeout an evaluation doesn't finish,
    other threads are unblocked or you can manually resume all threads.

    Alternatively, it's also possible to skip breaking on a particular thread by setting a
    `pydev_do_not_trace = True` attribute in the related threading.Thread instance
    (if some thread should always be running and no breakpoints are expected to be hit in it).

- The evaluation is deadlocked:
    In this case you may set the PYDEVD_THREAD_DUMP_ON_WARN_EVALUATION_TIMEOUT
    environment variable to true so that a thread dump is shown along with this message and
    optionally, set the PYDEVD_INTERRUPT_THREAD_TIMEOUT to some value so that the debugger
    tries to interrupt the evaluation (if possible) when this happens.
```

**Edit** The above error message went away after adding the following to my `launch.json` file for `VSCode`.

```
"env": {"PYDEVD_WARN_EVALUATION_TIMEOUT": "500"},
```

Overall config file.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "env": {"PYDEVD_WARN_EVALUATION_TIMEOUT": "500"},
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Edit** After this change, although the message did not appear for quite some time for `raw_data_result.count()`, it still ended up appearing after a very long time. It is my impression that there is some other issue occurring in the backend.

Even `print(raw_data_result.count())` never seems to finish executing.

**edit** running the same functions on a smaller number of collections results in a more instantaneous response across the aforementioned functions. Seems like it is related to the number of documents in the collection. The functions never finish in the situation where there are several million documents. Is there a fix?

---